# Give li elements class based on above ul class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of li elements and I want to give all li elements below the ul container an extra class based on the .login class. The login element isn't a parent element but in the same container. Would this be possible with jQuery or vanilla js?

```
 <ul class="submenu" id="sub0">
  <li class="menugroup dcjq-parent-li">
   <ul class="rightmenu login">
     <li><a href="/" title=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="/" title=""></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

   <li><a href="/"></a></li> <-----new class
   <li><a href="/"></a></li> <-----new class
   <li><a href="/"></a></li> <-----new class
    <li><a href="/"></a></li> <-----new class
    <li><a href="/"></a></li> <-----new class
    <li><a href="/"></a></li> <-----new class
 </ul>
```

Comment: *"Would this be possible with jQuery or vanilla js?"* - Yes!

Comment: Could you also possibly style the `li` elements using a simple child selector like `ul.login > li { background-color: #ff0000; }`

Comment: Well I dont want to give the children of the login ul an extra class - I want to give the next set of li elements outside the login container an extra class, based on the login element.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the requirement is. Shouldn't the li around the login menu item get the class too? And what if other li elements would come before the login li instead of after? And what do you mean by 'based on the login class'? Based on the existance of an element with that class? Based on the other class ('rightmenu') of that element, .... ?

Comment: Does the login class always get applied to ul in the first li child or will this change?

Comment: Also, as an alternative, maybe you can just add the class to ul.submenu, and use a selector like `ul.submenu.yourextraclass > li` to get to the li elements in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```js
$("ul.login")
.parents("li")//get ancestor li element
.nextAll()//get all next li elements
.addClass("active");//add desire class
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="submenu" id="sub0">
  <li class="menugroup dcjq-parent-li">
    <ul class="rightmenu login">
      <li>
        <a href="/" title=""></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/" title=""></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**References**

[.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

[.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

[.parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: I was unclear - i want the next set if li elements outside the ul container with the .login class to have an extra class, based on the element with the login class. Edited my question.

Comment: That worked perfect. Will mark as correct when I can. Thank you!

Comment: @Xeptor Glad that I helped you.